# $_GET Wordpress Get URL Variables Infusionsoft

Tags: php, wordpress, html, shortcode

So I am trying to get the email variable out of the URL of which works if I do it in the page template however then whenever you wish to change the form you have to open the files and change it instead of just posting it in the page editor.

The below code is what I have setup as a shortcode in my functions.php

```
function get_email() {
    return $_GET["inf_field_Email"];
}
add_shortcode('email', 'get_email');
```

The code **echo $_GET["inf_field_Email"];** works if I include it inside the php template so I know that isn't the issue.

However when I try to use the shortcode in the Wordpress page editor all it displays in the form field is the shortcode I entered **[email]** and does not return the Variable from the URL.

Here is the form field:

And FYI the URL provided works fine with the **echo $_GET["inf_field_Email"];** so I can also say its not the URL that's the issue.

**EDIT: Clarifying how the form is inserted into the page**

The form is inserted into the page editor so its being pulled in through the content loop correct. When i insert the code manually outside the loop and echo the $_GET it works fine but I need it to work inside the_content() loop.

**EDIT: Suggested that I dump the var and return the variable, still doesn't work**

```
function get_email() {
    $emailinput = $_GET["inf_field_Email"];
    var_dump($emailinput);

    return $emailinput;
}
add_shortcode('email', 'get_email');
```

Comment: How does your page template look? Is the shortcode passed to the template separately or as part of the_content() function?

Comment: The form is inserted into the page editor so its being pulled in through the content loop correct. When i insert the code manually outside the loop and echo the $_GET it works fine but I need it to work inside the_content() loop.

Comment: in your shortcode, try to see if you access the URL, by var_dumping before you return.

Comment: It just prints the following on the page but not in the form field: string(26) "example@example.co.uk"

Comment: just store in a variable and return the variable

Comment: See edited questions, this still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the form code inside the php page template instead of the wordpress CMS page. I believe this is an issue with Infusion Soft and wordpress working together in order to display shortcodes as values inside the embed infusionsoft forms.